# How to make split Jquery Mobile Layout for iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I really like the type of page shown here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

But I cannot find in the source anything that says where the "Anatomy" or anything on how to get the navigation bar and content area.

How do I make/get the content area and navigation area like the one shown in the demo?

Comment: This is just a matter of CSS, nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also looking for a solution to this as it's a very useful layout for navigating records. But viewing the source is a headache since the structure isn't simlar enough to the API and there's a couple dozen css classes interacting with each other.

But i did discover a split-view plugin which might work:
http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 2):

just as in the last answer - http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

There is a link to: https://github.com/asyraf9/jquery-mobile/

There is a repository zip file download link in the top left.

But when you get there, and you look at the file viewer and so on it seems kinda confusing. When you look at the files close enough they are the same resource doc files from the JQ Mobile site.

***The difference is in the file structure: demos\experiments\ you will see the a "splitview" directory. You can use the contents of that dir for reference.